# R & Spark-Scala Dataframes Processing time

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

*I am new to Spark world and my question might be not appropriate for many people. However, due to my curiosity I cant hold myself to ask this question.*

I have very large dataset, 500,000 rows and 2500 columns. while preparing this dataset I observed huge performance difference while preparing data for analysis between R & Spark dataframe. Essentially, Spark ML faster than R. Here is one article found over the internet and in general it is known. 
http://bigdata-madesimple.com/tools-in-the-data-armoury-r-vs-spark/

R code snippet: below code gets completed within 2 mins

```
for(columnName in 1:allNumericColumns){ 
     if(sum(is.na(dat_[,columnName])) > 0){
        dat_[which_,columnName] <- 0       
      }
}
```

Spark/Scala Code snippet: below code takes hours (more than 4 hours),

```
dat3_.schema.fields.filter(f => f.dataType == DoubleType).map(c => {
  if(dat3_.filter(col(c.name).isNull).count() > 0)
  {
    ///****Either
    dat3_ = dat3_.withColumn(c.name + "_isNull", when(col(c.name).isNull, 1).otherwise(0))
    ///***OR
    dat3_ = dat3_.withColumn(c.name, when(col(c.name).isNull, 0).otherwise(col(c.name)))
  }
})
```

After researching I found expensive operation is:

```
if(dat3_.filter(col(c.name).isNull).count() > 0)
```

However, If I just do simple replace of null with 0. It still takes an hour to finish the data transformation.

```
dat3_.schema.fields.filter(f => f.dataType == DoubleType).map(c => {
      dat3_ = dat3_.withColumn(c.name, when(col(c.name).isNull, 0).otherwise(col(c.name)))
    })
```

This is still unclear to me why there is huge performance or processing issue with Spark dataframe.

If anyone has some idea please clear my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have any cloud server to work with and you work on the local, using spark will increase your computation time. please check this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oItFZfzqqMY&index=32&list=LLcCiCxO6SjbBzEzz7zAhNsQ&t=0s

Comment: I might have missed to include that I have Google Dataproc Cluster (good size) for my Scala/Spark code processing. And R studio runs locally which gives me excellent response with same data. Since Spark code was taking time I was executing same code on cluster even big size cluster. However, I don't see any positive feedback with Spark/Scala code.